# How do I remove information from a Python list, then insert it into a new list?

Tags: python, list

I am using Python to create a program that uses Selenium to scrape a job-posting website, then turn the information of the scraped jobs into a series of lists. I will then take the information and turn it into a dataframe.

The issue is that not all of the lists are of the same size, as each job has 1-3 locations. I want to remove the extra locations, then insert each location into its own list.

So for example, if I had a list of:

`['Data Analyst', 'Dallas, TX, US', 'Orlando, FL, US', 'Raleigh, NC, US', '50,000']`

It would end up like:

`['Data Analyst', 'Dallas, TX, US', '50,000']`

`['Data Analyst', 'Orlando, FL, US', '50,000']`

`['Data Analyst', 'Raleigh, NC, US', '50,000']`

Comment: Are the lists always in the same shape? ['JOB', 'Location', 'Location', 'PRICE']?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the first element is the title and the last element is the salary, take those out, and iterate over the slice of the list starting at index `1` and ending before index `-1`.

```
job_info = ['Data Analyst', 'Dallas, TX, US', 'Orlando, FL, US', 'Raleigh, NC, US', '50,000']


title = job_info[0]
salary = job_info[-1]

all_job_info = []
for location in job_info[1:-1]:
    all_job_info.append([title, location, salary])
```

This gives you `all_job_info` which is a list of lists:

```
>>> print(*all_job_info, sep="\n")
['Data Analyst', 'Dallas, TX, US', '50,000']
['Data Analyst', 'Orlando, FL, US', '50,000']
['Data Analyst', 'Raleigh, NC, US', '50,000']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [extended iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) to extract your data, then recombine with a list comprehension.

```
title, *locations, salary = job_info
result = [[title, location, salary] for location in locations]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the indexes the simplest way would be:

```
New_List = Original_List[x:y]
New_Original_List = Original_List[0:x] + Original_List[y:len(Original_List)-1]
```

x and y are the indices of the portion of the original list that he wants removed.  You may need multiple pairs if they are not all grouped together.

Comment: 1. You can use `-1` instead of `len(Original_List) - 1`. 2. What are `x` and `y`? 3. This wouldn't do what OP asks anyway